How can I force my ExceptionMapper to be used when Jackson can't deserialize?
We're using JBoss EAP 7 with RESTeasy (of course) and Jackson (the System Property resteasy.preferJacksonOverJsonB is set to true).
We also have an ExceptionMapper which should catch all Exceptions:
public class StandardExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {
...
}

However, this is not called if the JSON I submit is faulty. I just get HTTP response code 400 with the error can't parse JSON.  Raw result: Not able to deserialize data provided.
Of course, this is not helpful at all. I do see the following in the log:
[org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson] RESTEASY-JACKSON000100: Not able to deserialize data provided:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "foo"
...

This is exactly the information I would like to catch in my StandardExceptionMapper!
I read in How to customize error response when deserializing failed that a more specific ExceptionMapper will win.
So the question is: How can I switch off those more specific Jackson mappers?
I tried the following in web.xml:
  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.disable.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.resteasy.api.validation.ResteasyViolationExceptionMapper,com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonParseExceptionMapper,com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonMappingExceptionMapper</param-value>
  </context-param>

This didn't work.
(Note: The ResteasyViolationExceptionMapper I already disabled before, because I wanted to handle validation myself.)
I also tried:
  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.use.builtin.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>

My StandardExceptionMapper was then called, but not much worked anymore...
How can I force Jackson's JSON deserialization Exceptions to be caught by my StandardExceptionMapper?

Try adding a more specific ExceptionMapper. For example create one for ExceptinMapper<UnrecognizedPropertyException>.

Thanks, I tried this. But it only worked after I saw in another StackOverflow question that I also have to annotate @Priority(1). If you want to post your comment as answer, I can accept it as official answer.

I think this is similar to
JSON serialization with root element does not work in RestEasy/Jettison/JBossAS7

We need to disable the default RESTEasy exception mappers that handle specific Jackson exceptions by adding a context parameter in web.xml \
Ensure that your StandardExceptionMapper is registered and can handle exceptions that are not caught by other mappers.
Updated web.xml

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.disable.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.JsonParseExceptionMapper,
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.JsonMappingExceptionMapper,
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.validation.ResteasyViolationExceptionMapper
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.use.builtin.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

Explanation:
resteasy.disable.providers: This parameter disables the specific RESTEasy providers that handle Jackson exceptions, such as JsonParseExceptionMapper and JsonMappingExceptionMapper.
resteasy.use.builtin.providers: This parameter disables the use of built-in providers, allowing your custom exception mappers to handle exceptions.
By disabling these providers, RESTEasy will fall back to your StandardExceptionMapper for handling exceptions that occur during JSON deserialization.

I wouldn't suggest using the resteasy.use.builtin.providers without a very good reason. You won't get any of the providers RESTEasy has built in.

I tried this, and my StandardExceptionMapper is called, but deserialization fails:
javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: RESTEASY003200: Could not find message body reader for type: class foo.bar.Test of content type: application/json
...
Caused by: org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: java.lang.String of media type: application/json
